# Excel VBA - display Skype Contact Card (Skype for Business)

Tags: vba, excel, skype, skype-for-business

Looking for a way to display Skype presence (Skype for Business) by Excel vba.

[I do see that Excel does have this capacity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBU40.png)
Excel -> File -> info has access/displays Contact Cards of the author of a given Excel document as well as the correct contact card of the last person who modified it.

The question is how to create a similar effect via vba code.

The current state of affairs is I already made a Userform that detects and extracts names of titled individuals from text written in the text box.
I have a correct name of a staff member in the program itself, now
I'd like for Skype Contact Card to appear on screen the same way the File->Info authors/modifiers do appear on screen.

Internet so far failed me in finding the answer.
I found http://users.skynet.be/fa258239/bestanden/skype4com/skype4com.pdf however solutions within seem not to work anymore (or on my version of Excel/VBA(?) [Skype4COM Objects cannot be created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVcFI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Skype for Business does not use Skype4COM - Skype for Business used to be Lync and uses the REST for interfacing via the UCWA library. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139603/excel-vba-skype4comlib-is-not-working-with-skype-for-business-sfb)