# Sending Message In VBA - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, skype-for-business

I want to send a message in Skype For Business (2016). I have seen some other articles and questions asked here, and a lot refer to a reference: **SKYPE4COMLib**. However, I cannot find this at all. Is it still possible to send messages in Skype For Business?

Comment: I have Skype for Business 2016 installed on my work computer, but cannot see this?

Comment: Well, I am supposed to add the reference in VBA tools>reference - however, SKYPE4COMLib is not listed here?

Comment: Just saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43172531/2521004) looks like that library is not compatible with SfB unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain it!